# Compilation error of class template instantiation C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, compiler-errors

I am having trouble with a compilation error as shown below:

C:\Users........................(35): note: while compiling class template member function 'void cs140::RenderVisitors::visit(cs140::Background &)'

Can anyone help to enlighten me on this? I've been stuck for a while now, searching the internet for sources that resemble this error, but they are all unrelated cases. Thank you.
Do note: the code below isn't compilable.

Header file

```
namespace cs140
{
    template <typename T>
    class Background
    {
    };
    template<typename T>
    class RenderVisitors 
    {
       public:
       void visit(Background<T>& background);

       private:

     };

   }
```

HPP file

```
namespace cs140
{
    template<typename T>
    void RenderVisitors<T>::visit(Background<T>& background)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like there should be more to that error. What is a HPP file and how is it different from the header file? Is it being included or compiled? Perhaps this might shed some light: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c27f608b864ad91).

Comment: Please post the whole error message.